# Not able to select more than 255 columns from Pyspark DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to select 500 columns from a Pyspark DatFrame. Getting error as "SyntaxError: more than 255 arguments"

```
Df2 = Df\
  .select("col1","col2","col3",...............,"col500")
```

Tried below approach also, bit did not work.

```
cols = ["col1","col2","col3",...............,"col500"]
Df2 = Df\
     .select(cols)
```

Both the approach is working for less than 255 columns.

**Note** : My Python version is 3.6

Please Advice me. Thanks.

Comment: Actually I want write the content of the DataFrame into Cassandra table but the column order in Cassandra table if different so using SELECT I wanted to rearrange the column. If I will select two times then again I need to JOIN the two dataframe and order will be mismatch.

Comment: The second case shouldn't result in the exception. And do you seriously write 255 columns by hand? Any reason to do it? If you want the order to match the schema, just pass it without enumerating explicitly. And if you really (like really) want to write it by hand. `df.createOrReplaceTempView("df"); spark.sql("SELECT col1, col2, ..., col500 FROM df")`

Comment: @pissall That's not correct.

Comment: The second case worked for me, very first time it through exception due to some other reason that I have fixed. Also the SQL option you have suggested that also very good ... I will try that as well ... thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After having conversation with @pissall, below are two workable solutions to select more than 255 columns:

**Case 1:**

```
cols = ["col1","col2","col3",...............,"col500"]
df2 = df.select(cols)
```

**Case 2:**

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df"); 
spark.sql("SELECT col1, col2, ..., col500 FROM df")
```

Comment: But where did you define df.dataframe